# Python gmail imap/pop issues

Tags: python, timeout, gmail, imap

I'm trying to write code to view messages from my g-mail, then search in the latest message for a certain phrase, that triggers a command.
But I'm having problems with connecting to my g-mail

```
from imapclient import IMAPClient

HOST = 'imap.gmail.com'
USERNAME = 'email'
PASSWORD = 'password'
ssl = False

server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

server.select_folder('INBOX')
print ('success')
```

I just added the 'success' at the end to make sure it worked, I'm using imap here but I tried pop which seems to be more confusing.
When I run this code i get this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Yousef/Desktop/parser.py", line 8, in <module>
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 152, in __init__
self._imap = self._create_IMAP4()
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 166, in _create_IMAP4
return imap4.IMAP4WithTimeout(self.host, self.port, self._timeout)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imap4.py", line 13, in __init__
imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, address, port)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\imaplib.py", line 197, in __init__
self.open(host, port)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\imaplib.py", line 294, in open
self.sock = self._create_socket()
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imap4.py", line 16, in _create_socket
return socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self._timeout)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Someone please help me with this, because this is my first time using imap/pop.
when I put ssl to true, I get this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Yousef\Desktop\parser.py", line 8, in <module>
server = IMAPClient(HOST, use_uid=True, ssl=ssl)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 152, in __init__
self._imap = self._create_IMAP4()
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 164, in _create_IMAP4
self._timeout)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 171, in __init__
imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\lib\imaplib.py", line 197, in __init__
self.open(host, port)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 177, in open
self.sock = wrap_socket(sock, self.ssl_context, host)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 144, in wrap_socket
ssl_context = create_default_context()
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 127, in create_default_context
context.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\backports\ssl\core.py", line 654, in load_verify_locations
self._ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py", line 669, in load_verify_locations
_raise_current_error()
File "C:\Users\Yousef\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-
packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: []
```

nvm i found a solution, thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: You _must_ use SSL.  Google does not offer an insecure port for IMAP.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me this :

Comment: raise exception_type(errors)
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: []

Comment: Please give the entire stack trace, then.

Comment: If you found a solution, please answer your own question for future people who find it, or delete it if it was something silly.  As it is, this question does not help future visitors to StackOverflow.